# Convert object to another format

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Currently I've an object in this format -

```
{'Esfera': '+2.5,+3.4', 'Cilindro': '120,100'}
```

But I want to convert it in below format -

```
[{'Esfera':'+2.5', 'Cilindro':'120'},{'Esfera':'+3.4', 'Cilindro':'100'}]
```

Can somebody please help to convert it using Javascript with minimal code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick solution in JS.

```js
const arr = [];
const obj = {'Esfera': '+2.5,+3.4', 'Cilindro': '120,100'};
for(let x in obj.Esfera.split(","))
    arr.push({Esfera:obj.Esfera.split(",")[x],Cilindro:obj.Cilindro.split(",")[x]});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is more automated way to do.

```js
const obj = { Esfera: '+2.5,+3.4', Cilindro: '120,100' };

const keys = Object.keys(obj);
const len = obj[keys[0]].split(',').length;

const res = [];
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  res.push(
    keys.reduce(
      (val, cur) => ({
        ...val,
        [cur]: obj[cur].split(',')[i]
      }),
      {}
    )
  );
}
console.log(res);
```